# not able to use fingerprint authentication for overlay window attached in service

Tags: authentication, window, overlay, fingerprint

I am creating an 'App Lock' app, I used one foreground service to show an overlay window for fingerprint authentication, and fingerprint authentication is working fine when my app is in the foreground, but when my app goes to the background or is killed, then I am not able to authenticate the user via fingerprint authentication in service. I always get "onAuthenticationError" callback error(Authentication operation canceled). if fingerprint authentication does not work in service when the app is in the background or killed, then there is an app on the play store, that has a feature to authenticate users via fingerprint even when the app is in the background or killed.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ultra.applock

I tried Biometric prompt API and fingerprint manager API both do not work in service if the app is in the background or killed.